# How do I return the errors and their context from my Next.js api route?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am unsure as to what I should do when I throw a particular error for example, here is my code:

```typescript
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const customer = null;

    if (!customer) throw Error("Could not get customer");
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "hello world",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.error(error);
  }
}
```

I want to throw an error when the customer is null, which I think it does, but on the front end, I only get the generic error:

```
{"message":"Request failed with status code 500","name":"AxiosError","stack":"AxiosError: Request //...
```

On the client, I have no idea what caused this error.

My question is, how am I supposed to handle such errors so that the client would clearly know that, in this particular case, *Error happened, because the customer is null*?

Should I return json object instead of throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism. You should create your own error messages and send them, for example, as JSON:

```typescript
// app/api/route.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const customer = null;

    if (!customer) return NextResponse.json({ message: "Could not get customer" }, { status: 400 });

    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "Hello world",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "An expected error occured" }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Consume the error on the client with `axios`:

```js
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/api");
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  }
}
```

Consume the error on the client with `fetch`:

```js
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("/api", { method: "POST" });
    // Other errors:
    if (!res.ok) {
      const errorData = await res.json();
      console.log(errorData);
    } else {
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    }
    // If there is Network error:
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```